# math with python find x of P(abs(|X|)>X)

Tags: python-3.x, probability

Let X be standard normal random variable. Find value x such that P(|X|>x)=0.2.

So I use the ppf method of scipy.stats.norm, but can I use ppf(0,8) ?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `ppf(0, 8)`?

Comment: Well I get a result, but what should I do to take into account the absolute value ?

Comment: What would be the difference of taking it into account vs. not taking it into account?

Comment: answer is close to 1.28158 right?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: P(|X| > x) = P(X > x or X < -x). I think you can figure out P(X> x) and P(X < -x) from the cumulative distribution function. By the way, you'll need to determine how P(X > x) and P(X < -x) are related to P(X > x or X < -x).